# PHP: How to echo a variable if it is valid

Tags: php

I would like to echo the PHP variable $record->myword it is valid, but not echo it if it is empty or null. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<tr>        
    <td>myword</td>
    <td><? echo "$record->myword"; ?></td>
</tr>
```

This code echoes the text "$record->myword", rather than the value, and echoes even if it is invalid. Can anybody help?
Thanks from Belgium

Comment: i made a question. Your site is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand the question, but here's what I think:

```
<tr>
     <td>myword</td>
     <?php
     if ($record->myword != '' && $record->myword != null) {
         echo "<td>".$record->myword."</td>";
     }
     ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: wow you did it and I thank you with this help <tr>
<?php
if($record->bureau != '' && $record->bureau != null){
 echo "<td>Bureau</td><td>".$record->bureau."</td>";
}
?>
</tr>      works fine!

Comment: THe check mark under the upvote/downvote number on my answer.